# Getting more data for each item looped over - *ngFor

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I have built a table for types of documents and their associated systems.

Using *ngFor, I am looping through an object array named `this.doctypes` and want to get each `doctype`s system and it's URL with a web request. Using a common `for` loop I can get each system the doctype uses and it's URL. However, because the HTML's *ngFor doesn't kick in until after the constructor loads, the final system placed in the `this.systems` object array is the final one looped over. Also, I do not believe you can access local arrays with *ngFor meaning I can't push the item to an array and clear the array after each doctype is iterated over.

I have created a [Stackblitz for this issue.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dt33yq)

What methods can I use to correct this?

Comment: You forgot to save the stackblitz

Comment: @bugs Question has been updated.